# How to move a msmq message to a subqueue

Tags: c#, msmq, system.messaging

Using the `System.Messaging` classes, how do I move a msmq message (in this case a poison message) to a subqueue?

Seems like this should be simple, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Aren't subqueues just for WCF usage?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use a normal queue for that?  Like a dead letter queue?

Comment: Subqueues are an MSMQ feature. "Move" is available from the unmanaged api: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701502(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @010110 I want a subqueue mainly so that it is easy to move them back to the main queue from the GUI once I've fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does not appear to be possible. Ayende [resorts to the unmanaged API](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-esb/blob/master/Rhino.ServiceBus/Msmq/MsmqExtensions.cs#L36) in Rhino Service Bus, and if he can't do it then I certainly can't.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, I just learned today via a colleague that [Microsoft finally added support for addressing subqueues in 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kenkilty/archive/2013/06/21/accessing-msmq-subqueues-programmatically.aspx).

Comment: this link is dead