# Moving poison messages to processing queue

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, msmq, message-queue

I'm trying to add functionality to a system support website that will move messages from the poison queue back to the processing queue. This is what I've attempted so far:

```
// path = "FormatName:DIRECT=OS:machine-name\private$\queue-name";

var poisonQueue = new MessageQueue(path + ";poison");
var processingQueue = new MessageQueue(path);

foreach(var message in poisonQueue.GetAllMessages())
{
    processingQueue.Send(message);
}

var poisonCount = poisonQueue.GetAllMessages().Count();
var processingCount = processingQueue.GetAllMessage().Count();
```

Unfortunately, `Send()` doesn't seem to be doing anything. The debugger shows the counts as:

```
poisonCount: 6
processingCount: 0
```

Comment: Just a thought, why not explicitly declare your variables? I've learned this the hard way; never allow the compiler to choose variable types for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure: How to move messages from poison queue to back to main queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33252196/azure-how-to-move-messages-from-poison-queue-to-back-to-main-queue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move poison messages to **retry queue** and then messages will be processed again

please look here for more details

- [MSMQ and Poison Messages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2007/02/12/msmq-and-poison-messages.aspx)
- [Handling Poison Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703179%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I ended up using the unmanaged API that you linked to. That worked for me

Comment: For those wondering how to move messages between queue and subqueues (including poison) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585609/how-to-move-a-msmq-message-to-a-subqueue